# CMD + V in excel causing extra blank spaces at end of text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When attempting to paste data from one cell in a sheet, to another sheet/cell I find that some text has leading extra white space at the end of the cell. For instance, if I am pasting the text 'ABC' from one cell to another, Im finding an extra white space at the end so it looks like: 'ABC '. Why does this happen?

I've tried using the TRIM func, but it's not resolving the issue. Id really like to resolve this issue

Thank you,

I've tried using the =TRIM(A1). The issue remains where at the end of the text there's an extra white space for some, but not all text.

Comment: Are you sure it is a space?

Comment: I am. There's always a random extra space at the end of the text in the column IM copying to, but not the one Im copying from

Comment: So if it is a space then trim() removes leading and trailing spaces so no problem.

Comment: Do you recommend doing something like `=TRIM(LEFT(A2, LEN(A2)-1))`?

Comment: So will that work in all cases? Why not find out what that character is? May be a hard return or some such, but if that character is not there then you will remove the last character that may be wanted.